# Connecting to Tizen TV via the Tizen IDE or sdb

Tags: connection, tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-sdb, tizen-sdk

I assume Samsung forums devoted to Tizen would the the first place to resolve this issue but after reading through them it seems that nobody has succeeded with this and the support has not provided any valuable information either so I'll just hope that there are some SO users working with Tizen TVs who have encountered and maybe solved this themselves.

I am trying to connect to a Tizen Smart TV from the Tizen IDE to deploy a native application. As far as I understand this functionality is quite new and supported only in [recent firmware releases](http://www.tizenexperts.com/2015/09/developer-wow-developer-mode-now-available-on-samsung-tizen-tvs/). I've updated to the latest firmware (1411) but still neither the Tizen IDE (namely the Connection Explorer component) neither the native `sdb` command line tool seem to work ( I've described the behavior in detail in [this](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/180241c0163b926c?forumID=b45a709abf3ed079) post to the Samsung Tizen forum).

The `sdb` tool seems to fail with any command other than `sdb connect`. Connection seems to succeed but after that any other command like `sdb dlog` or `sdb shell` simply print that the connection has been closed. Wireshark also approves this - every TCP message gets a `CLSE` reply.

Is there anyone on SO who has successfully deployed a native application via the developer mode on a Tizen Smart TV and could share the recipe?

Comment: @Gagu - http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/180241c0163b926c?forumID=b45a709abf3ed079, Samsung support said that the newest SDK should work, haven't tried it out yet though.

Comment: me too downloading the same...lets hope for the best

Comment: @Gagu - let me know if it works:)

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Did you succeed in connecting to the TV?

Comment: @prudhvi I still haven't had time to get back to that, will post when I do.

Comment: @prudhvi no with the SDK 2.4 rev2 it seems that I was initially on the wrong path - Samsungs TVs support only NaCl applications not native ones and I am now struggling to understand how I can debug those. At least eclipse on Windows tells me debugging is not available under Windows.

Comment: @prudhvi ok I just got a bit further - the SDK 2.4 rev2 seems to connect but it cannot push the certificate on the TV.

Comment: you can use sdb push on sdk w/ emulator but not a shell ? weird
"failed environment shell, so it will retry shell command."

Comment: I'm still having this problem

Answer (score 5):

adding your workstation's ip to the TV's hosts is a must.
on the tv, go to apps, put focus on my apps and click 1,2,3,4,5 on the RCU.
a pop up message with ip input comes up.
enter your workstation's ip and reboot the tv (turn off, turn on)
try to reconnect, good luck

Comment: Thank you, very much. Absolute time saver:)

Comment: can we do this in an emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: when I tried to connect to Samsung Smart TV from Tizen SDK or sdb, It didn´t work.

For me, the solution was to define in the Samsung Smart TV ip config the **IP from the Macbook where I am running the Tizen SDK** (according to the recomendation in [this link](http://www.tizenexperts.com/2015/09/developer-wow-developer-mode-now-available-on-samsung-tizen-tvs/))

So, in my private network the **Samsugn Smart TV** was on ip 192.168.0.102, and the **Notebook** was on ip 192.168.0.103

I opened the developer mode in **Samsugn Smart TV**, it was ON and I change there the IP to 192.168.0.103 (It was the private Macbook ip)

After that, the sdb command and SDK work and my demo app is running on the Smart TV:

```
$ sdb connect 192.168.0.102:26101
connecting to 192.168.0.102:26101 ...
connected to 192.168.0.102:26101
```

My software and hardware versions are Samsung (JU6500) and Tizen SDK Version : 2.4.0_Rev7

I hope it answer could help you, may be you have the same problem... It tooks me a lot of time find this solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try to Menu -> System-> Smart Security -> Settings: Deactivate network security
Then reboot device. Power off wait 30sec. power on.
Try to connect via the instr. of Samsung. Worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me neither anymore. The tv does not open the necessary port. And that was from one day to another without having changed anything. I am currently avoiding tizen right now. When i get back to it and have new info I´ll share.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after reset the TV to factory settings. For me, upgrading TV firmware from 1430 to 1443 did the trick.

To upgrade firmware:
Menu->Assistance->software update->update now

Good Luck